# AjaxJspTag is not defined

Tags: java, jsp, taglib, ajaxtags

I'm trying to use AjaxTags, especially the htmlContent tag. The jsp looks as follow:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://ajaxtags.sourceforge.net/tags/ajaxtags" prefix="ajax"%>

<h1>HtmlContent Tag Demo</h1>

<div style="font-size: 90%; width: 650px;">
<p>The <code>ajax:htmlContent</code> tag fills a content area (e.g., DIV tag) with an HTML
fragment from another resource. You may find this tag useful for including blocks of information in
a sidebar when the user clicks a link or form field. This tag is a more simplified approach to the <code>ajax:portlet</code>
and <code>ajax:tabPanel</code> tags.</p>
<p>Shown below are three different ways of executing the AJAX event: link, radio button, and
select field.</p>
</div>

<h3>HtmlContent in Action</h3>

<div id="modelDescription" style="background-color: EAE9AF; width: 300px; height: 100px;"></div>
<div id="htmlContentForm">
<p>Select by ANCHOR link.</p>
<ul>
  <li><a href="javascript://nop/" class="contentLink">Ford</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript://nop/" class="contentLink">Honda</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript://nop/" class="contentLink">Mazda</a></li>
</ul>
<form id="htmlContentForm">
<p>Select by RADIO option.</p>
<input type="radio" id="makeford" name="make" value="ford" class="contentRadio" /> <label
  style="display: inline; cursor: pointer;" for="makeford">Ford</label><br />
<input type="radio" id="makehonda" name="make" value="honda" class="contentRadio" /> <label
  style="display: inline; cursor: pointer;" for="makehonda">Honda</label><br />
<input type="radio" id="makemazda" name="make" value="mazda" class="contentRadio" /> <label
  style="display: inline; cursor: pointer;" for="makemazda">Mazda</label><br />
<br />
<p>Select by SELECT option.</p>
<select id="selmake" name="selmake">
  <option value="">Select one</option>
  <option value="ford">Ford</option>
  <option value="honda">Honda</option>
  <option value="mazda">Mazda</option>
</select></form>
</div>
<div id="progressMsg" class="indicator" style="padding-top: 5px; display: none;">Loading...</div>
<div id="errorMsg"
  style="display: none; border: 1px solid #e00; background-color: #fee; padding: 2px; margin-top: 8px; width: 300px; font: normal 12px Arial; color: #900"></div>

<ajax:htmlContent baseUrl="${contextPath}/htmlcontent.htm" sourceClass="contentLink" target="modelDescription"
  parameters="make={ajaxParameter}" />

<ajax:htmlContent baseUrl="${contextPath}/htmlcontent.htm" sourceClass="contentRadio" target="modelDescription"
  parameters="make={ajaxParameter}" />

<ajax:htmlContent baseUrl="${contextPath}/htmlcontent.htm" source="selmake" target="modelDescription"
  parameters="make={selmake}" eventType="change" />
```

The htmlcontent.htm is produced by another jsp, which contains only "HalloText" as string, nothing else (no html tags or similar). And this page can be loaded in the browser.

When i load the first jsp, then i get following as output:

```
<h1>HtmlContent Tag Demo</h1>

<div style="font-size: 90%; width: 650px;">
<p>The <code>ajax:htmlContent</code> tag fills a content area (e.g., DIV tag) with an HTML
fragment from another resource. You may find this tag useful for including blocks of information in
a sidebar when the user clicks a link or form field. This tag is a more simplified approach to the <code>ajax:portlet</code>
and <code>ajax:tabPanel</code> tags.</p>
<p>Shown below are three different ways of executing the AJAX event: link, radio button, and
select field.</p>
</div>

<h3>HtmlContent in Action</h3>

<div id="modelDescription" style="background-color: EAE9AF; width: 300px; height: 100px;"></div>
<div id="htmlContentForm">
<p>Select by ANCHOR link.</p>
<ul>
 <li><a href="javascript://nop/" class="contentLink">Ford</a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript://nop/" class="contentLink">Honda</a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript://nop/" class="contentLink">Mazda</a></li>
</ul>
<form id="htmlContentForm">
<p>Select by RADIO option.</p>
<input type="radio" id="makeford" name="make" value="ford" class="contentRadio" /> <label
 style="display: inline; cursor: pointer;" for="makeford">Ford</label><br />
<input type="radio" id="makehonda" name="make" value="honda" class="contentRadio" /> <label
 style="display: inline; cursor: pointer;" for="makehonda">Honda</label><br />
<input type="radio" id="makemazda" name="make" value="mazda" class="contentRadio" /> <label
 style="display: inline; cursor: pointer;" for="makemazda">Mazda</label><br />
<br />
<p>Select by SELECT option.</p>
<select id="selmake" name="selmake">
 <option value="">Select one</option>
 <option value="ford">Ford</option>
 <option value="honda">Honda</option>
 <option value="mazda">Mazda</option>
</select></form>
</div>
<div id="progressMsg" class="indicator" style="padding-top: 5px; display: none;">Loading...</div>
<div id="errorMsg"
style="display: none; border: 1px solid #e00; background-color: #fee; padding: 2px; margin-top: 8px; width: 300px; font: normal 12px Arial; color: #900"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">new AjaxJspTag.HtmlContent({baseUrl: "/spring-mvc-hsqldb/htmlcontent.htm", parameters: "make={ajaxParameter}", sourceClass: "contentLink", target: "modelDescription"});</script>

<script type="text/javascript">new AjaxJspTag.HtmlContent({baseUrl: "/spring-mvc-hsqldb/htmlcontent.htm", parameters: "make={ajaxParameter}", sourceClass: "contentRadio", target: "modelDescription"});</script>

<script type="text/javascript">new AjaxJspTag.HtmlContent({baseUrl: "/spring-mvc-hsqldb/htmlcontent.htm", eventType: "change", parameters: "make={selmake}", source: "selmake", target: "modelDescription"});</script>
```

And firebug report 3 Errors:

```
AjaxJspTag is not defined <script type="text/javascript">new Aja...arget: "modelDescription"});</script> hello.htm (Zeile 46)
AjaxJspTag is not defined <script type="text/javascript">new Aja...arget: "modelDescription"});</script> hello.htm (Zeile 48)
AjaxJspTag is not defined <script type="text/javascript">new Aja...target: "modelDescription"});</script> hello.htm (Zeile 50)
```

Can someone give me a hint, what is wrong (what i'm doing wrong)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This refers to the fact that there is no javascript library included containing definition of the class *AjaxJspTag*.

The libraries javascripts should be included as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scriptaculous/scriptaculous.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/overlibmws/overlibmws.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajaxtags.js"></script>
```

I also recommend to check this page for reference: [AjaxTags JavaScript-JSP Library 
 - QuickStart](http://ajaxtags.sourceforge.net/quickstart.html) (You are especially interested in step 2. described there)

Comment: thanks....the quick start is made by older ajaxtags version (1.3) and i'm using 1.5.5. But this was, what i'm missing. My scripts section looks like:<script type="text/javascript" src="ajaxtags/js/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ajaxtags/js/scriptaculous/scriptaculous.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ajaxtags/js/overlibmws/overlibmws.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/ajaxtags/js/ajaxtags.js"></script>